# Spacy: how create a tokenizer with your own delimiter

Tags: python, spacy, tokenize

I need to create a tokenizer that will split my text using commas.

For that text

```
"5g, dynamic vision sensor (dvs), 3-d reconstruction, neuromorphic engineering, neural networks, humanoid robots, neuromorphics, closed loop systems, field programmable gate arrays, spiking motor controller, neuromorphic implementation, icub, relation neural network"
```

I want to get this output

```
['5g', 'dynamic vision sensor (dvs)', '3-d reconstruction', 'neuromorphic engineering', 'neural networks', 'humanoid robots', 'neuromorphics', 'closed loop systems', 'field programmable gate arrays', 'spiking motor controller', 'neuromorphic implementation', 'icub', 'relation neural network']
```

I tried to use custom tokenizer

```
def custom_tokenizer(nlp):
    pattern = re.compile(r'([\sa-z0-9\(\)-]+)')
    return Tokenizer(nlp.vocab, 
                     token_match=pattern.finditer)

nlp.tokenizer = custom_tokenizer(nlp)
```

But it returns me

```
['5g,', 'dynamic', 'vision', 'sensor', '(dvs),', '3-d', 'reconstruction,', 'neuromorphic', 'engineering,', 'neural', 'networks,', 'humanoid', 'robots,', 'neuromorphics,', 'closed', 'loop', 'systems,', 'field', 'programmable', 'gate', 'arrays,', 'spiking', 'motor', 'controller,', 'neuromorphic', 'implementation,', 'icub,', 'relation', 'neural', 'network']
```

I've checked pattern and it works ok.
How can I stop split text with whitespaces?

Comment: https://kite.com/python/docs/builtins.str.split `your_str_variable.split(',') ` might be an option

Comment: If all you need is a list of strings, there's no need to use spaCy: `text.split(',')` will do.    Or do you want each item to be a Token object? (Why though?) If so, you could just replace all spaces with underscores and then pass the text to `nlp()`.